# Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32. C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please can you help with the C# code below. The code work find when I used numerical value but when I test the code using a value like K083271 I have the error:

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user codeAdditional
>   information: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a
>   Int32.

Debugging gives `usercount = 0`

C# Code

```
using (SqlConnection con = new    SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Molecular"].ConnectionString))
    {
       con.Open();

 using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT  count(*)

         from Patient  where MBID = @SearchCriteria ", con))
      {
           cmd.Parameters.Add("@SearchCriteria", SqlDbType.Int).Value= Convert.ToString(txtSearchCriteria.Text);

             DataTable dt = new DataTable();
             SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
             int userCount = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
             da.Fill(dt);

          if (userCount > 0)
             {

                 using (SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT  *

                        from Patient  where MBID = @SearchCriteria ", con))
                   {
                         int searchcriteria4 = int.Parse(txtSearchCriteria.Text);
                          cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchCriteria", searchcriteria4);
                          DataTable dt4 = new DataTable();
                          SqlDataAdapter da4 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd4);

                           da4.Fill(dt4);

                                if (da4 != null)
                                {
                                    GridViewClinicalPatientDetails.DataSource = dt4;
                                    GridViewClinicalPatientDetails.DataBind();
                                }
                         }
                            return true;
                        }
           else
              {
                            Response.Write("<script>alert('Patient does not exist. Check Patient MBID')</script>");

                            txtSearchCriteria.Text = "";
                            return false;
              }
        }
```

Comment: Are you talking about the line `int searchcriteria4 = int.Parse(txtSearchCriteria.Text);`? How would you expect K083271 to parse to an integer? (hint: you can't, validate that textbox first)

Comment: What do you expect? You can't write literals into ints.

Comment: `"The code work find when I used numerical value ..."` - Because numeric values are numeric, but non-numeric values are non-numeric.  If you want to parse a string as an integer, that string needs to represent an integer.

Comment: I fail to understand why people -1 this question for having incorrect content and misusing int.parse(), if it had correct content he wouldn't be asking it. it's ok to be wrong. your question was well put, and we found the fault in no time due to it. +1

Comment: @Stavm I think the problem is that the OP seems to know exactly what the problem is: trying to parse something like "K083271" into an int. But they give any explanation of why they think that would work or what they expect to happen. Or is it that they want to do more graceful validation? We don't know, and that essentially makes the question unanswerable

Comment: K is not a number, it is a letter. You cannot convert a letter to a number.

Answer (score 1):

Check user input before trying to perform the query: if user entered something that is not an integer, warn him with something such "please insert a number" and do go on.
you can use something like this:

```
int idToSearch;
if (!int.TryParse(txtSearchCriteria.Text, out idToSearch)
{
    // warn somehow the user
}
else
{
    //go on with your query, you can safely use idToSearch for you parameter value
    ...
    cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchCriteria", idToSearch);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use belo
command.Parameters.Add("@SearchCriteria", 0);